# EF Core - async await problem with the same dbcontext class

Tags: .net-core, async-await, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5

kWhen executing my async code I get following error:

```
InvalidOperationException: A second operation was started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext.
```

Now I have an API Controller which makes a call to a HelperClass:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<string> Get(int id)
{
    var JsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
    };

    Application foundApplication = await ApplicationFunctions.GetApplicationById(_dbContextNoInheritance, id);
    if (foundApplication == null)
    {
        ErrorModel.ErrorMessage = "No such application found!";
        ErrorModel.StatusCode = 404;
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ErrorModel);
    }
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foundApplication, JsonSettings);
}
```

The Method GetApplicationById is inside another class which makes a call to a stored procedure inside my database, there is much more code but for example:

```
Sepa sepa = await SepaFunctions.GetSepaByApplicationId(dbContext, Application.Id);
if (sepa != null)
{
    await PayeeFunctions.GetPayeeBySepaId(dbContext, sepa.Id);
    await PayerFunctions.GetPayerBySepaId(dbContext, sepa.Id);
}
```

Now the method GetPayeeBySepaId:

```
public async Task<Payee> GetPayeeBySepaId(AntragDBNoInheritanceContext dbContext, int sepaID)
{
    List<Payee> foundPayee = await dbContext.Payees.FromSqlRaw("Exec GetPayeeSepa {0}", sepaID).ToListAsync();
    if (foundPayee.Any())
    {
        await LoadRelatedPayeeInformation(dbContext, foundPayee);
        return foundPayee.FirstOrDefault();
    }
    return null;
}


public async Task LoadRelatedPayeeInformation(AntragDBNoInheritanceContext dbContext, List<Payee> toLoadPayees)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        toLoadPayees.ForEach(payee =>
        {
            PersonFunctions.GetPersonByPayeeId(dbContext, payee.Id);
            AddressFunctions.GetAddressByPayeeId(dbContext, payee.Id);
            BankInformationFunctions.GetBankInformationByPayeeId(dbContext, payee.Id);
        });
    });
}
```

Now I know that you cant use the dbContext in multithreading scenarios but according to the documentation the "solution" would be to always async await every operation which I am doing. When I debug it works fine but in runtime it crashes in the GetPayeeBySepaId function. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `GetSepaById` isn't shown and half of the code consists of black boxes. Esp. these method calls inside the `ForEach`. If they're async theys should also be awaited.

Comment: @GertArnold the method calls inside the `ForEach` are not async so they are not awaited. I wrapped an  `await Task.Run()` around them. Does this make a difference? Considering the implementation its the same like in the `GetPayeeBySepaId` just with other tables and without a `LoadRelatedData` function.

Comment: @GertArnold Also it was a mistake by my side, it crashes in the `GetPayeeBySepaId` function

Comment: Then the issue solved?

Comment: @TinyWang I solved it by creating a new instance of my dbContext with the using statement